# If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $\int_a^b fg=0$ for any $g$ defined on $[a,b]$, then $f(x)=0, \forall x \in [a,b]$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

Here's the question from the book:

[image]

Here's my response:

[image]
But I don't think I answered the actual question asked.  I proved if $f(x)=0$, then $\int_a^b fg=0$, but I think they want me to prove it vice versa : if $∫_a^b fg=0$, then $f(x)=0$, which I can't figure out how to prove/

------------------------EDIT---------------------------------

Here's the solution from the solution manual, but I have a question about it:
(Analysis With an Introduction to Proof, by Steven R. Lay)

[image]

Does this still hold when g doesn't equal f ??

Comment: Hint: $f$ is integrable on $[a, b]$.

Comment: infact you have proved onle one side

Comment: What book is this from?

Comment: Analysis With an Introduction to Proof, by Steven R. Lay

Comment: What do you mean "does this still hold when g doesn't equal f?"

Comment: The solution starts with let g=f then.... well, what about when g != f?

Comment: @DanaHill Please, if you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that you proved the wrong thing. As you said, you want to prove that if $\displaystyle \int_a^b fg =0$ for all integrable $g$, then $f\equiv 0$.

Here's how we can do that:

For $\varepsilon>0$ take an integrable function $g$ such that $|f(x)-g(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x \in[a,b]$. One way you could obtain such a $g$ is to just perturb $f$ continuously on some tiny interval, by less than $\varepsilon$.

Then
$$\int_a^b f^2 = \int_a^b f(f-g) + \int_a^b fg$$
$$= \int_a^b f(f-g).$$

But since $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, it is bounded by some $M$
so
$$\left|\int_a^b f(f-g)\right| \le M\int_a^b |f-g| < \epsilon(b-a)M.$$

Since we can do this for every $\varepsilon >0$, we have that
$$\int_a^b f^2 =0.$$
Since $f$ is continuous, then $f^2$ is a nonnegative, continuous function whose integral is zero. This implies that $f^2 \equiv0$ on $[a,b]$, which implies that $f \equiv 0$ on $[a,b]$.

Comment: wait.  How did you get rid of the ∫_a^b fg that was added?  It just went poof?   nevermind.. cuz it equals zero.

Comment: @DanaHill By the hypothesis of the question, $\int_{a}^{b} fg = 0$

Comment: Yep. $\int_a^b fg =0$ for all integrable $g$.

Comment: It just occurred to me that we can immediately just say that $\int f^2 =0$, since f is integrable.

Comment: Why can you immediately say that without knowing what f is??

Comment: You know that $f$ is continuous, and thus is integrable. So we know $\int fg =0$ for all integrable $g$, so take $g=f$.

Answer (score 1):

the result is known as "Fundamental lemma of calculus of variations"

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_lemma_of_calculus_of_variations

Comment: Nice, thanks for the link.